# emacs (orgmode) does not accept links with non-english characters (osx)

Tags: emacs, org-mode

This problem has been partly solved (see below).

I'm using gnu emacs (on OSX) with orgmode and I'm having trouble linking to files with non-english-alphabet characters.

Examples:

this works:
file:~/dor

this doesn't:
file:~/dør

Is it possible to fix this?

PARTIAL SOLUTION:

This problem was partly solved by updating from emacs 23 to 24 (which, at the moment, is "pretest"). (I updated orgmode with package el too but that did not make a difference)

These files now work:

file:~/dør.txt
http://www.dører.no (would open in firefox but with various combinations of symbols for ø)

This still doesn't work:

file:~/dør (file:~/dor works)

Comment: It works fine with current stable (7.8.09), I suspect your version of Org is too old.

Comment: great, I'll test that asap (do you use osx?)

Comment: done, folders still don't work with æøå but url's and txt's now do

Comment: Works fine on ArchLinux -- please report your problem on the Org-mode mail list, we may help from there.